# What is my issue with variable in SAS code?

Tags: variables, sas

Can somebody help me please?
I am running small program in SAS. .
Data import works fine, but I am getting error with variable pocet_bodu.

Do you have any idea why is it happening please?

**ERROR**:

> ```
>          85         
>          86         %web_open_table(WORK.IMPORT);
>          87         
>          88         proc univariate data=work.import normal plot;
>          89         var pocet_bodu;
>          ERROR: Variable POCET_BODU not found.
>          90         histogram pocet_bodu/normal;
>          ERROR: Variable POCET_BODU not found.
>          91         qqplot pocet_bodu/normal (mu=est sigma=est);
>          ERROR: Variable POCET_BODU not found.
>          92         
>          93         run;
>     
>      
>      NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
>      NOTE: PROCEDURE UNIVARIATE used (Total process time):
>            real time           0.00 seconds
>            cpu time            0.00 seconds
>        
>  94         
>  95         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
>  107
> ```

**CODE:**

```
%web_drop_table(WORK.IMPORT);

FILENAME REFFILE '/folders/myfolders/data-mining/data/du1_1.xlsx';

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE=REFFILE
DBMS=XLSX
OUT=WORK.IMPORT;
GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;

PROC CONTENTS DATA=WORK.IMPORT;
RUN;

%web_open_table(WORK.IMPORT);

proc univariate data=work.import normal plot;
var pocet_bodu;
histogram pocet_bodu/normal;
qqplot pocet_bodu/normal (mu=est sigma=est);

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Error was in imported excel file... it needed to define var name there as well :)